# Using regEx's to route incoming requests (web server)

Tags: regex, node.js, httprequest

I am considering building a web server which routes requests by matching the url to a regex from a list of services that define a regEx property - the first service to match the url handles the request.

I am looking for advice. Has anyone done anything like this? Does using regexs like this sound like a bad idea? If so, what are the possible side effects?

Comment: Well, since it's not uncommon to pass, say, URI-encoded JSON objects as requests, I'd say yes, basing your web server on regexes is probably a bad idea.  Is there a reason why you're writing your own web server instead of using an already established web server?

Comment: all requests will be passed on to another web server. Just using node as a proxy

Comment: Okay....why do you want to roll your own web server to use as a proxy instead of, say, Apache, nginx, IIS, Plackup, etc, etc, etc, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is a little bad idea. You do not need to reinvent the wheel. For a web server, you will have probably basic requests, /users/all/phones or /items/cool/ascending/top10.. and you will not need advanced regular expressions. Even if you need, a good library Express handles them too. Have a look at [ExpressJS Routing](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#routing), it is already set and probably optimized, so you will not need to hassle with your own routing code.